# Visual studio 2010 Asynchronous Programming

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asynchronous

I ran the below code in VS2010, but i have faced the issue like

```
id = 1, status = waitingforactivation, method = "{null}", result = "{not yet computed}"
```

Then I searched and found, needs to enable the async and await in VS2010.
Then by using AsyncCtpLibrary dll reference, I have enabled it. But still vs2010 does not return the response.

I got the response in VS2012 but I need to implement that one in the project which is developed in VS2010.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
Task<string> task = GetCustomerDetails(); //PushCustomerDetails();
task.Wait();
var x = task.Result;
}

static async Task<string> GetCustomerDetails()
{
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Credentials=new NetworkCredential("demo","demo"),
    };

    var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var result1 = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("URL")
    return result1.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Just don't use VS 2010. It's not just the IDE.  It *can't* support the newer .NET runtime and C# compilers that introduced `async/await` support.  The Community edition of VS 2017 is *free* and equal or better than VS 2010 professional. *Why* don't you use a supported Visual Studio edition?

Comment: In *newer* versions of Visual Studio you can use the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package from NuGet to add `async/await` support to .NET 4.0 projects. It doesn't support VS 2010 though

Comment: I have changed the line var result1 = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("URL"); to var result1 =httpClient.GetStringAsync("URL").Result; It is works fine..But still exists on post method call.

Comment: No it isn't. You are *BLOCKING* the call. This is a *synchronous* call now, not an asychronous one. It's the exact opposite of what you asked. Why do you insist on using an unsupported Visual Studio version when the supported version is free?

Comment: Also note that *HttpClient* itself was introduced in .NET 4.5/VS 2012. *TLS 1.2* was introduced then as well. Even if you add HttpClient with a NuGet package and convert all calls to blocking ones, you won't be able to connect to any site/service that requires TLS 1.2. You are asking to use an unsupported IDE, that only targets an unsupported .NET runtime, use unsupported classes that may not be able to connect to the sites you want anyway

Comment: I needs to implement that one VS2010 only because the project which i'm going to implement developed in it,

Comment: That's not a valid answer. Why don't you *change the IDE?*. If you wanted to target Windows XP or .NET 4.0, you can do so with any edition. And as I said, 2017 is free.  You can't use any of this code in VS 2010. The project you produce with VS 2010 may not be able to *connect* to web sites at all because of TLS

Comment: Anyway, long story short : you can't. You can't use `async/await` or `HttpClient` in VS 2010 and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Task<string> task = GetCustomerDetails(); //PushCustomerDetails();
   var x = task.Result; //Result is already waiting
}

static Task<string> GetCustomerDetails()
{
   var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
   {
      Credentials=new NetworkCredential("demo","demo"),
   };

   var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new      
MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   return httpClient.GetStringAsync("URL")
}
```